# Calculate date of birth given age

Tags: r, date

I have the data below.

```
ID  = 201
Age = 40
```

**How do I calculate the Date of birth using this info and the `Sys.Date()` function?!**

Answer (score 2):

We can create a `POSIXlt` date using the current system date, decrement it by the number of years in `Age`, and then convert back to an R date:

```
d <- as.POSIXlt(Sys.Date())
age <- 40
d$year <- d$year - age
as.Date(d)

[1] "1979-12-29"
```

Of course, this means that everyone would appear to have today as their birthday, but maybe that isn't the point of the exercise you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

With package `lubridate`, you can make it like below

```
library(lubridate)
age <- 40
birth <- ymd(Sys.Date()) - years(age)
```

such that

```
> birth
[1] "1979-12-29"
```